# How to make a red shield

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

How do you make a red shield in Minecraft? I know how to make a shield but the game doesn’t let me craft it. Do I need to be a certain xp level? And then when I have the shield how do I make it red?

Comment: Just look at the wiki.

Answer (score 1):

To craft a  Shield, first put any wooden planks and an iron ingot in the pattern of your crafting table as shown below:

[image]

Then, get a banner of the color and pattern you wish and put it in the crafting grid with the shield.

Further reading:
[Wiki page on Shields](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Shield)